# How to install OpenCV3.0 in ubuntu os?

Tags: opencv3.0

Please provide me a complete guide to how to install opencv for python3 in ubuntu 16.04. I have tried some tutorials from pyimagesearch.com but i am getting some fatal error at 88% of build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following link will help you to install opencv for ubuntu 16.04.
link: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html